# How to show custom menu title?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-actionbar, android-menu

I've set custom theme for MainActivity in manifest `android:theme="@style/Theme.Custom"`, which is:`<style name="Theme.Custom" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"> <...>`

This MainActivity acts as navigation host fragment and in navigation map I've set my other fragment as startup. In that fragment I call:

```
override fun onCreateView(<..>

    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.supportActionBar?.title = "title"

    return <...>
}

onCreateOptionMenu <... ..>
onOptionsItemSelected <..>
```

All of my elements that I specified in that menu appears. When my MainActivity's theme is `"Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"` title appears, but when I set it to my custom, title doesn't appear whatsoever. Why is that?

Update:

[image]

Let's say I want this action bar. My problem that "Action Bar" text doesn't appear.

Comment: You said in your theme that you wanted `NoActionBar`, so if you want an action bar, you have to use the `Toolbar` widget and add it. The reason why you see nothing is because `(activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.supportActionBar` is null (it doesn't crash because you're correctly using the `?`, but it also doesn't make the action bar magically appear for you)

Comment: In my activity_main.xml I do include `Toolbar` widget. `(activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.supportActionBar` is not null. I do see the items that I specified, but not the title.

Comment: Hmm ok, then I may be wrong though you didn't mention that you were using toolbar. Now where are you telling android which toolbar to use?

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the title for each menu item in activity_drawer.xml in Menu folder?
If not try this

```
 <item
     android:id="@+id/nav_home"
     android:title="@string/menu_home" />
```

Comment: Do menu items need titles? Because I do not need names for menu items. Basically I need that title, which appears on the left of the menu - so called main title.

Comment: Basically when I used to have classes that extended AppCompatActivity, I just wrote `supportActionBar!!.setTitle(getString(R.string.title))` and everything was fine, but when I changed to extending Fragment, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Yes, menu items need title, it will appear on the left side of Action bar by default.

Comment: I'm using `tools:ignore` to ignore the title. If I change to text, nothing happens. I will update my question with what I'm trying to achieve.